# Trouble outputting a space in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, masm, x86-16

I am having a tiny problem with my assembly code. Everything runs correctly however I cannot get the output to have a space between each other. For example, `abc` should look like `a b c`. I tried to use `mov dh, space` in my `charloop` routine, so that it would inset a space automatically.

However it does not show up when I run the program. I am curious to find out what I am doing wrong here.

```
.data
message db "The characters of the ASCII Table between 33 and 127 are : $"
space db " $"

.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov ah, 09h
lea dx, message 
int 21h

mov cx, 95

mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 33 

charloop:                  
    int 21h  
    inc dl ;starting from 0 
    mov dh, space           
    dec cx

    jnz charloop  

exit:    
    mov ax, 4C00H
    int 21h

main endp
endp
```

Comment: You should maybe comment a bit more what you think you do in the assembly code. I can see that this is wrong just by reading it, but I cannot explain it to you as I failed to know what you believe to do. Your main problem seems to come from the fact that you have a confusion between the string itself and the address of the string, but I cannot say much more from what I see.

Comment: Are you using EMU8086 or is this MASM or TASM?

Answer (score 1):

I only see one DOS system call (`int 21h`) inside the loop.  I assume you're using the print-character system call, since you're incrementing `dl` rather than modifying a string in memory.

Are you sure it even looks at `dh`?  I forget if the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki has a link to a list of DOS system calls.  Also, since you're loading the first byte of `space` into `dh`, there's no point having a two-byte constant with a `$` terminator.

It might be easier to start with a string like `db 33, " $"`, and increment the first byte in it.  Then you still only need one system call in the loop.  Otherwise you need to alternate printing characters and printing spaces.

```
; set up registers as appropriate, with  OFFSET string wherever the DOS print-string system call wants it
; Note that this is different from loading the first character like your code does into `dh`

.charloop:
    int   21h
    inc   byte ptr [some_register]
    jns   .charloop           ; will fall through on 127 -> 128, sign bit set
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer this in a way you may understand I'll propose a solution that is similar in nature to the code you already have.

[Int 21h/ah=02h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm) is documented in Ralf Brown's [interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm) as:

> DOS 1+ - WRITE CHARACTER TO STANDARD OUTPUT
>
> ```
> AH = 02h
> DL = character to write
>
> Return:
>     AL = last character output (despite the official docs which state
>     nothing is returned) (at least DOS 2.1-7.0)
> ```

The character to write must always be in *DL*. What you could do is place a space into *DH* before the loop, print the current character and then temporarily exchange ([*XCHG*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XCHG.html)) the *DH* and *DL* registers, print the space, and the exchange *DH* and *DL* back to the way they were. The code could look like:

```
mov cx, 95

mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 33 
mov dh, space

charloop:                  
    int 21h       ;Print the character
    inc dl        ;starting from 0 
    xchg dh, dl   ;Swap DH and DL temporarily
    int 21h       ;Print the separating character (space)
    xchg dh, dl   ;Swap DH and DL back to the way they were
    dec cx
    jnz charloop
```

Rather than place a space and $ sign inside a string like you did with `space db " $"` you could have simply written `mov dh, space` as `mov dh, ' '`

You appear to be using *EMU8086/MASM/TASM* which supports defining a constant using the [*EQU* directive](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Instructions/I77_0130_equ_directive.htm). You could define a separator character constant (similar to #define in *C*) with something like this near the top of your program:

```
SEPARATOR equ ' '
```

When you need to use it, it would look like:

```
mov dh, SEPARATOR
```

This way you can change the separator character you want to print by simply changing the value of the *SEPARATOR* constant.

---

Using DOS's Writestring interrupt ([Int 21h/AH=09h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm)) you could write the character and the space with a single interrupt.

> DOS 1+ - WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
>
> ```
> AH = 09h
> DS:DX -> '$'-terminated string
>
> Return:
>    AL = 24h (the '$' terminating the string, despite official docs which
>    state that nothing is returned) (at least DOS 2.1-7.0 and NWDOS)
> ```

Create an output buffer where the first character will be filled in as you go, the second character with the separator you want (space) and the 3rd character will be the terminating character `$`. Your code could look like:

```
.data
message db "The characters of the ASCII Table between 33 and 127 are : $"
outputstr db 0, ' ', '$'     ; First character will be where we place char to print, 
                             ; second char is a space, $ is end of string


.code
main proc

mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov ah, 09h                  ; AH=9 write string
lea dx, message             
int 21h

mov byte ptr [outputstr], 33 ; Place starting character into first
                             ;    byte of output string 
lea dx, outputstr            ; Address of outputstr in DX for call to DOS Writestring
mov cx, 95

charloop:                  
    int 21h                  ; AH=9 to write a string  
    inc byte ptr [outputstr] ; Increment the byte at beginning of the output string 
    dec cx
    jnz charloop  

exit:    
    mov ax, 4C00H
    int 21h

main endp
endp

ret
```

---

Once you become more proficient and writing assembler you could remove the need for the *CX* counter. You could simplify a bit by using the trick Peter Cordes mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37178769/3857942) by using [*JNS*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html) (Jump not SIGN). When you use [*INC*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/INC.html) the instruction will set the SIGN flag based on the result. Since you want to end when you reach 128 you can loop while the sign bit is clear (zero). The value 128 has bit 7 (left most bit) being a 1. Bit 7 also happens to be the SiGN bit when dealing with a *BYTE*. This trick only works in your case because you want to end when you reach 128. This means you can avoid using *CX* as a loop counter.